# passing in a function to get return value or values

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I have a template looking like this:

```
struct add_node_value_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    add_node_value_visitor(){}

    template <typename T>
    void operator() ( const T& value) const
    {
        boost::lexical_cast<std::string, T>(value);
    }

};
```

The problem I have is that the visitor is used inside a for loop iterating over a bunch of values, and the resulting string of values needs to be one string, currently this would produce a bunch of separate strings, which is not what I want, so to solve this problem I thought I'd add a function pointer to the ctor of this struct so that I can pass in a function to concatenate the resulting string of each loop iteration and create one string.  Then if I want to use this struct where I do not need a concatenation, I can still do that.  The question is whether I should use a function pointer or is it possible to do this with something like boost::lambda?

Or would boost::function be easier to use?

Comment: Is my question that incomprehensible or does no one know?

Comment: It is quite early in some places... at this time people in America will still be sleeping, and some people in Europe (like me) will still be crawling towards a mug of coffee to wake up. Time for coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
struct add_node_value_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const std::string&)> concat_func_t;

    add_node_value_visitor(const concat_func_t& concat) : concat_(concat){}

    template <typename T>
    void operator() ( const T& value) const
    {
        concat_(boost::lexical_cast<std::string, T>(value));
    }

private:
    concat_func_t concat_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not performing the concatenation in place?

```
struct add_node_value_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
   std::ostringstream st;
   template <typename T>
   void operator() ( const T& value ) {
      // change concatenation logic here if required (separators...)
      st << value;
   }
   std::string const & str() const {
      return st.str();
   }
};
```

Comment: I might use this function in a place where no concat is needed, so doing it in place reduces my flexibility I guess.

Comment: Will the extra complexity (code, place of call) compensate? Having to write two different functors that take 10 lines of code, of which most are plain boiler plate vs. adding extra complexity (you will need to add the function pointer/concat functor to the class, plus create the extra function/functor... will that be simpler? less error prone? what do you really achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more general-purpose visitor would be in order, leaving it up to the caller what to do with the string representations.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct to_string : boost::static_visitor<std::string>
{

    template <typename T>
    std::string operator() ( const T& value) const
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string, T>(value);
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::variant<int, double> > vec;
    vec.push_back(42);
    vec.push_back(3.14);
    std::string result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i) {
        result += boost::apply_visitor(to_string(), vec[i] ) + ' ';
    }
    std::cout << result;
}
```